# EF Core adding an extra column to the entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I have an EF Core 3.1 entity query that is failing because an extra column is being added to the entity (let's call the entity `ClientRequestDetails`).

We can call the in question `ClientRequestSearchPartialClientRequestId`. There are no columns with that name in my database (hence why the query fails).

I do have a "fake" entity called `ClientRequestSearchPartials` and it does have a `Key` column called `ClientRequestId` (by "fake" I mean that it does not have a backing table in the database. It is constructed manually when the service gets specific "search" calls).

I cannot figure out why my `ClientRequestDetails` entity would add this column itself.

`ClientRequestSearchPartial` does have a list of `ClientRequestDetails` on it. Would that cause `ClientRequestDetails` to add a column that is an joining of the table name and its key?

If so, how can I stop this?

Comment: Can you please add relevant code? Entity model configurations, query causing the problem, etc.

Comment: It's unclear what's the purpose of the "fake" entity you are talking about, but fundamentally after registering a class as entity (doesn't matter if it has associated database table, view or nothing), all navigation properties introduce conventional relationships with FK at the dependent side. Either remove that fake entity, or remove the collection from it. If you need something to hold the result of a projection query, don't register it as entity - `Select` supports projecting to arbitrary type.

Comment: One of your entities has a property of type `ClientRequestSearchPartial`. So EF Core has added the table and relationship to your model. You need to find that property and ensure it is `[NotMapped]`.